# Flutter Cupertino DateTime picker language to Czech

Tags: ios, flutter

I am trying to create a Cupertino DateTime picker, but it displays English format of date and time and I need it in Czech.

This is my code:

`

```
   Center(

        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(90, 0, 90, 10),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.25),
                  spreadRadius: 2,
                  blurRadius: 4,
                  offset: Offset(2, 5), // changes position of shadow
                ),
              ],
            ),


            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              child: Material(
                child: ListTile(
                  onTap: () {
                    showCupertinoModalPopup(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => SizedBox(
                        height: 250,
                        child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                          initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
                          onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newTime) {
                            setState(() => whenDate = newTime);
                          },
                          use24hFormat: true,
                          minimumYear: DateTime.now().year,
                          maximumYear: DateTime.now().year,
                          minimumDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year,DateTime.now().month,DateTime.now().day),
                          mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  title: FittedBox(
                    child: Row(
                      children: [

                        Icon(CupertinoIcons.calendar, color: "#2ec76e".toColor(),),

                        CupertinoButton(
                          child: Text("${whenDate.day}. ${whenDate.month}. ${whenDate.year}", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade800, fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),),
                          onPressed: () {
                            showCupertinoModalPopup(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (BuildContext context) => SizedBox(
                                height: 250,
                                child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                  initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
                                  onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newTime) {
                                    dateFieldClicked = true;
                                    setState(() => whenDate = newTime);
                                  },
                                  use24hFormat: true,
                                  minimumYear: DateTime.now().year,
                                  maximumYear: DateTime.now().year,
                                  minimumDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year,DateTime.now().month,DateTime.now().day),
                                  mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),

                      ],),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),`
```

I tried to search for solution on web, but I've only found how to do it in German, and when I searched for same package in Czech there was no such a thing.

If you know any package for Czech language localization please send it here.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this my adding :

```
locale : const Locale('cs','CZ')
```

Hope this helps!